# Using Azure DevOps with Ansible

Tags: azure-devops, ansible, azure-pipelines

I want to deploy an Ansible playbook through Azure DevOps but the Ansible extension requires us to have a Linux VM configured with Ansible in order to deploy our playbook. Is there a way to deploy the Ansible playbook through Azure DevOps withougt needing to configure a Linux VM first?

Comment: No you need a linux system. Using WSL is (well sort of since it is a vm itself....) an alternative: https://www.jeffgeerling.com/blog/2017/using-ansible-through-windows-10s-subsystem-linux

Comment: use hosted agent?

Comment: May I know this status? Does Agent machine choice suitable for you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To run this Ansible extension, `Linux VM` just be one of choice. If you don't want use VM, you can choose another method: `Private Linux agent`.

Just install a [private linux agent](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/v2-linux?view=azure-devops) in your Linux machine.

Then during the pipeline configuration, select `Agent machine`.

[image]

This method do not need you create a linux VM and create SSH endpoint with that VM. Just install linux agent into machine, then the pipeline can run with that.

**Note:**

Do not forget the prerequisites: The Playbook and Inventory files be located on a private Linux agent.